# Flexslider not loading. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, flexslider, typeerror

I am receiving the following error on each page on my site with Flexslider on it.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Flexslider fails to initialise and a slide out tab is also blocked from loading.

The error is within my main plugins .js file

An example page on the live site is here:

http://dev.lwk-home.com/recent-installation-photos/white-gloss-kitchen-island.php

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's your error? please be more specific, what you try to achieve

Comment: This is the error from Chrome console log: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on 2 lines in the app.js file

Comment: That question could not be any clearer

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Seems to have been related to how the files were concatenated and missing ; from the end of plug in files, which doesn't cause a problem when the files are loaded individually.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused because either you have not added the script files that are needed in your code.Or you might be even adding your script file more than once that might lead to conflicts.I think in your case  you forgot to load the `jquery.isotope.min.js` , `flexslider.js` or `lightbox.js` file

Comment: Thanks for you swift response. The isotope, flexslider and lightbox js is in the app.js file. This was working yesterday and I've reverted the app.js file to a known working version but still the same error!

Comment: It may be also caused due to conflicts between various libraries